# Remove consecutive elements from string list JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist

Got a List of elements:

```
String[] temp = new String[]{"NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"};
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(temp));
```

need to remove elements "EAST" and "WEST" if they consecutive:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (list.get(i).equals("EAST") && list.get(i + 1).equals("WEST")) {
            list.remove(i);
            list.remove(i + 1);
        }
    }
```

After this code, list contains:

```
[NORTH, SOUTH, SOUTH, WEST, WEST]
```

I need:

```
[NORTH, SOUTH, SOUTH, NORTH, WEST]
```

How to remove consecutive elements from list?

Comment: What happens when you remove an element in the middle of a list, let's say at `i` index? The element previously at index `i+1` will switch to index `i`.

Comment: @MaksymPecheniuk Not related to OP's question.

Comment: @imabot IF loop remove and add this line list.subList(i,i+2).clear(); to get the required output.

Comment: As a few people have pointed out, you need to account for the fact that your first remove is shifting the list, causing your second remove to point to the wrong place.  However, I would suggest that, rather than trying to account for this, you should be creating a new list.  Copy the elements from one to the other, only after you've peeked ahead to be sure you want to.  Another issue you'll have is with the list N, W, W, E, E, N, you will only be removing the inner W, E and leaving N, W, E, N.  You should keep processing your list until it finds no removals.

Comment: Another approach, if these are really intended to be directions in a very regular map of blocks, is just to figure out where the path ends, then just make a new minimal route that gets there.  This will change N, W, N, E, S, E, S, W, S into just S.  But it might not be true that N, W is the same as W, N if the distances are not consistant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
    if (list.get(i).equals("EAST") && list.get(i + 1).equals("WEST")) {
        list.remove(i);
        list.remove(i);
    }
}
System.out.println(list);
```

**Output:**

```
[NORTH, SOUTH, SOUTH, NORTH, WEST]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] temp = new String[]{"NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"};
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(temp));
         for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
                if (list.get(i).equals("EAST") && list.get(i + 1).equals("WEST")) {
                    list.remove(i);
                    list.remove(i);
                }
            }
         System.out.println(list);
```